# XCode shell script error

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I just moved over to a new MacBook Air (10.8) and a  64-bit project that compiled before gives me  *Shell Script Invocation Error: /bin/sh failed with exit code 2*

It looks like XCode 4.6 is failing on one of the intermediate files, saying *unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'* in a file ending in .sh

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank

Bill

Comment: do you know which .sh file it is or do you need help figuring that out from within Xcode?

Comment: Here's then end of the error log:  

/Users/billferster/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MovingPicture-hcmztqjnatzylkburxulgmdynyqg/Build/Intermediates/MovingPicture.build/Debug/MovingPicture.build/Script-E004D330137B9E5B00FDC604.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/Users/billferster/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MovingPicture-hcmztqjnatzylkburxulgmdynyqg/Build/Intermediates/MovingPicture.build/Debug/MovingPicture.build/Script-E004D330137B9E5B00FDC604.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2